# Venn Diagram tool to help with learning set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, math-software, visualization

I want to use Venn Diagrams to help me to develop confidence and skill in set theory, including various proofs.

I found this tool online: https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=eb7ef0469ad23a2c5782e8770da04529

but unfortunately it seems broken and just hangs when I click submit.

I want to be able to highlight regions in a 3-circle Venn Diagram according to  descriptions like $A \subset B \setminus C$ etc.

This package for Python looks lile it could handle it: https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib-venn/ but the trouble is the mental energy I want to use on learning set theory would be taken up with learning to use the package, from what I've tried so far.

Any recommendations for good online tools or ready-made Python scripts to do what I'm looking for would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're asking for technical advice with wolfram alpha or some other program. This probably doesn't belong to this site.

Comment: I don't think that is correct - I'm asking for recommendations for alternatives, citing two tools I've tried as evidence of me trying to solve my problem.

Comment: Can I recommend paper and a pen/pencil/crayon/marker?

Comment: @hmakholmleftoverMonica Whilst doing it manually with pen and paper is good, a tool to validate the conclusion you have arrived to is also helpful when learning something new

Answer (score 1):

Using a computer program for something like this will invariably be more challenging than simply drawing them out yourself. Your circles never need to be completely accurate.